# Gradle try to compile before download dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, libs

The project has a lot of dependencies modules (We are using Nexus). When we try to download updated dependencies, it tries to compile before download them, so Android Studio find compile errors because it still doesnt has the libs, and its stop the process to download the full libs. So its like a snake that eat itself.

Do you have some ideas to fix this? For example, how to say to Gradle "download first dependencies, after try to compile"

Thanks.

Comment: You do synchronize Gradle. it will download all the dependencies

Comment: Yes, It try to do it, but, when it find a error in compilation because there a library it doesnt have, but for compile it need it (this lib is our own module that is upload to Nexus and liked to Maven). It cant get it.